# Reddit API - Requesting Access Token using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am having trouble with the POST request format for retrieving the access token with the Reddit API. I am following the instructions for [OAuth2](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2) and was able to parse the URL for the initial 'code' after the user grants permission but I don't know what to include in the post request exactly. This is what I have so far, where returnCode is the code parsed from the URL, but I get a 401 response.

```
async function fetchToken(returnCode) {

    const form = new FormData();
    form.set('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
    form.set('code', returnCode);
    form.set('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:3000/')

    const response = await fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        authorization: `Basic clientID + clientSecret`
      },
      body: form
    }).then(r => r.json())
    console.log(response);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this from Node or from the browser? Why are you using `mode: "no-cors"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a `FormData` request body which will have a content-type of `multipart/form-data`, not the required `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Try using `URLSearchParams` instead...

```js
const form = new URLSearchParams({
  grant_type: "authorization_code",
  code: returnCode,
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/"
})
```

Your *authorization* header is also incorrect. HTTP Basic authentication requires you to base64 encode the username and password

```js
const credentials = Buffer.from(`${clientID}:${clientSecret}`).toString("base64")

const res = await fetch('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token', { 
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`
  },
  body: form
})
if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
return res.json()
```

Comment: I'm using Node. I made the changes but I'm getting 401- Unauthorized. I'm pretty sure the id, secret, and code are correct but I'll go through everything again. Thanks for the tip on formData, I had kinda used patchwork code from what I had found and wasn't aware.

Comment: @Adam I missed the "Basic" keyword in my headers. Fixed now